# Custom dual list angular 2

Tags: html, angular

There is a problem with the custom dual list in angular 2, when you select items from the left list and make a drag and drop on right list items from left list move/add to the right list.

Is there a way to stop that behavior?

```
<custom-dual-list DragEvent= [sort]="keepSorted" [source]="sourceWeeks"
[key]="key" [display]="display" [filter]="filter"
[(destination)]="confirmedWeeks" height="265px" [format]="format"></custom-dual-list>
```

Is there any other way to achieve two lists on the page without facing this issue/bug?

Comment: would it be possible to provide a plunker

Comment: one problem i see `DragEvent=` is not assigned any value. you can make it black to avoid any issue `DragEvent=""`